# Duplicate draw line a bit wider

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I try to draw a speaker with the below code, I get a wider middle line:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\def\w{15pt}
\def\h{6pt}
\node[draw,rectangle,minimum width=\w,minimum height=\h] (base) {};
\draw (base.south west) -- ++(-\w/3,-\h) -- 
  ([xshift=\w/3,yshift=-\h]base.south east) -- 
  (base.south east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

See output below:

[image]

I know it maybe introduced by drawing the same line two times, but what's wrong?

Comment: `outer sep=0pt` in the node options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kill the `outer sep` for the `\node`:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\def\w{15pt}
\def\h{6pt}
\node[outer sep=0pt,draw,rectangle,minimum width=\w,minimum height=\h] (base) {};
\draw (base.south west) -- ++(-\w/3,-\h) -- 
  ([xshift=\w/3,yshift=-\h]base.south east) -- 
  (base.south east) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If the node is not needed for other purposes, then the rectangle can more easily be drawn by the path operator `rectangle`, for example:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \def\w{15pt}
  \def\h{6pt}
  \draw
    (0, 0) rectangle (\w, \h)
    (0, 0) -- (-\w/3, -\h) -- (\w+\w/3, -\h) -- (\w, 0)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]